# Trying to pu Edittext on Support map fragment

Tags: java, android

Hi i'm developing an app where i'm using a support ma fragment but when i try to put an edittext on map along with textview nothing is shown on map i mean the textview and editext are not visible on map i dont now where i'm going wrong so please if someone can assist me here
Here is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_above="@+id/viewpagerTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    >
    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nearby"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_shape"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/Maps"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        map:cameraTilt="30"
        map:mapType="normal"
        map:uiCompass="true"
        map:uiRotateGestures="true"
        map:uiScrollGestures="true"
        map:uiTiltGestures="true"
        map:uiZoomControls="false"
        map:uiZoomGestures="true" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerbackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#B07986CB"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpagerTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Put your `LinearLayout` below map fragment. Hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `FrameLayout` instead of main `RelativeLayout` and also to overlap  your `LinearLayout` with id viewpagerTop keep it below your `Fragment`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below format?

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/Maps"
    ............ />

<LinearLayout
    .............>
   <CustomTextView
       .......... />
   <TextView
       .......... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Other views